# Pseudo elements and media queries are being ignored

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pseudo-element

I've encountered two weird problems and think they might be related.
First one is - I want to create shadow under my div like in this tutorial here http://codepen.io/haibnu/pen/FxGsI. 
But for whatever reasons all pseudo elements for this tasks are ignored.
I'm using bootstrap, so here's the markup:

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="content" class="col-sm-4">
           <div id="article">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

where #article is the div under which I want the shadow.

css is mostly like in the provided link, although I tried many other options, but whatever I do in &:before or &:after, it has no effect at all.

And then I've noticed that all styles in my media queries won't work without !important, although media queries are placed at the very end of css file .

Maybe there's one reason for these  problems, so what can it be? And what can I do to solve them? (I've googled a lot, but the prob remains)

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:
Pseudo elements are working, but media queries still don't work without !important. I can post it as a separate question (since now I see these two are not related), but if there's an answer, please help me. I'm using scss and this is how they look (placed at the very end of the .scss file):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 761px) {
    h3 {
        width: 50% !important;
        }
}
```

Comment: you need to show all your code, cus this works for me https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/804y6bzr/1/

Answer (score -2):

After all I got these shadows and I think the reason for them not showing was that I use scss and my pseudo elements were nested like this:

```
#article {
        position: relative;

             #article:before {
             z-index: -1;
             position: absolute;
             content: "";
             bottom: 15px;
             left: 10px;
             width: 50%;
             top: 80%;
             max-width:300px;
             box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
             transform: rotate(-3deg);
               }
            }
```

But they worked only when I put them apart:

```
#article {
        position: relative;
    }
             #article:before {
             z-index: -1;
             position: absolute;
             content: "";
             bottom: 15px;
             left: 10px;
             width: 50%;
             top: 80%;
             max-width:300px;
             box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
             transform: rotate(-3deg);
            }
```

I hope, this is the case.